c++11 is it possible to create an interface with a function that allows various return types T or const T&?
I want to create an interface for classes that return a message.
My problem is that sometimes it will be better to return a string and sometimes a const string&.
What would be the best way to give inheriting classes the possibility of choosing the return type?
struct Verbose{
   // my message is a class member
   virtual const string& getMsg()const=0;

   // my message is created in the function
   virtual string getMsg()const=0;
};

Instead of this interface, I'd like something like this,
so as to offer this flexibility
struct Verbose{
   virtual myPrintableType getMsg()const=0;
};


return type is not part of the function signature, thus you have a redefinition error.
Can you illustrate what you actually want to achieve in order to be able to give you a relevant answer?

You can use ref-qualifiers for your member functions:
struct Verbose{
   virtual const std::string& getMsg() const& = 0;
   virtual std::string getMsg() const&& = 0;
};

struct Derived: Verbose {
    std::string s{"xxx"};
    const std::string& getMsg()const& {
        std::cout << "const string&\n";
        return s;
    }
    std::string getMsg()const&& {
        std::cout << "string\n";
        return "yyy";
    }
};

First version will be called only if your object is an l-value, i.e. it's considered safe to return member field by const reference. Second version will be called for r-values.
    Derived d;
    std::cout << d.getMsg() << std::endl;  // calls 1st overload
    std::cout << Derived{}.getMsg() << std::endl;  // calls 2nd overload

This is assuming that you want to have different behavior depending on   value category. If it's not the case and you need different return types for the same value category, then you need 2 different functions.

The function cannot choose -- you can only ever return one type. Overloads (same function name with different types) only work on parameter types -- and yes, if your functions would take different parameter types, they could return different result types as well.
However, the caller can certainly call one or the other function, if it can make that decision. Like I have this API:
template <typename T> const T& get() const requires (!std::is_scalar_v<T>);
template <typename T> T get() const requires (std::is_scalar_v<T>);

Of course, I can only do that because the caller knows what it will be getting. And I'll probably remove the scalar version eventually.
In your case, messages are often just base-classes, and you could generally just always return a std:unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr (depending on how your messages work). Of, if it's really just strings, just decide on one version.

Unfortunately it is not possible to do exactly what you described, since the overloading based on return type is impossible.
You can use constness though
struct Verbose{
  
   virtual const string& getMsg()const=0;

   //Either return string
   virtual string getMsg()=0;

   //Or a reference
   virtual string& getMsg()=0;
};

If you want to use a copy of the string in the calling code, you can use const function that returns a constant reference. This function overloading is more "universal" because it lets user decide what to do with a string and does not force them to perform a copy.
